# opencv : How to set Project Dependencies in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, opencv

I have four projects:

- cv

  cxcore

  highgui

  TemplateMatching

---

**The project dependencies**:

- project cv depends on cxcore

  project highgui depends on cxcore

  project TemplateMatching depends on cv, cxcore, highgui

---

but there are still some errors:

> Build started: Project: highgui, Configuration: Debug Win32
>
> .....
>
> **LINK : ....\bin\cxcore100d.dll not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link**
>
> cvcap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol *cvFree* referenced in function _cvReleaseCapture
>    cvcap_vfw.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol *cvFree*
>    cvcap_vfw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvReleaseImage referenced in function "void __cdecl icvCloseCAM_VFW(struct CvCaptureCAM_VFW *)" (?icvCloseCAM_VFW@@YAXPAUCvCaptureCAM_VFW@@@Z)
>   image.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cvReleaseImage
>   loadsave.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cvCreateImage
>   loadsave.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cvFlip
>   image.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvSetImageROI referenced in 
>   ....\bin/highgui100d.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 31 unresolved externals
>
> .....
>
> highgui - 56 error(s), 0 warning(s)
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

I don't  konw how to figure it out....
How can I make "TemplateMatching" use the functions in the cv/cxcore/highgui projects?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using c++ (or c)? Is TemplateMatching your own project where you are trying use OpenCV? I am asking just to understand your problem better so that maybe i can help.

Comment: it is c++, yes, i try to use OpenCV's source code

thaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want your own project (TemplateMatching) to use OpenCV, you don't have to build the Open CV projects, just link to the OpenCV libraries, cv.lib, cxcore.lib and highgui.lib.

If you still want to build the OpenCV projects, it seems from the errors that the HighGui project is not linking to cxcore.lib. That is the reason for the errors you are getting.

I assume you installed OpenCV 1.0 on Windows with the typical settings?

**EDIT**:
The libs, like cxcore.lib, are "stubs". These libaries are basically placeholders that inform the linker that the implementation of the functions is in the DLL. Therefore you have to include these libraries in the link, and make sure that your executable knows where to find the DLLs that implement the functions.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works after I add cxcore.lib to "Additionan Dependencies".

The relationship between lib and dll confused me ...
why the opencvs's dlls ( C:\Program Files\OpenCV\bin ) must be added to the Environment variables path?
Dani van der Meer, could you tell me How it work?
thx.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click a project and select Add References. Select the Projects tab, highlight the projects you want to reference from the current project, and click OK. In the class files, use (C#) using statements to reference the namespaces.

Comment: Same error? It's hard to give additional advice based on the info you gave. Try right clicking on the solution, select properties, and select project dependencies. It's also helpful to try building projects individually to see where it breaks.